# Installing .NET 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net-3.5, .net

My installation of Windows Server 2008 already has .NET 3.5. But I need to install SP1. I downloaded the exe from:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displayLang=en

When I double click to run it, nothing happens. For a second, I see the hour glass indicating that it's attempting to do something, but after that nothing. I tried "Run as Administrator" and restarted the server with no luck.

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the 237 MB download dotnetfx35.exe?  That was the standard 3.5-SP1 installer.

If you run MBSA, and it detects that 3.5-SP1 is recommended, use that download link.  That file should be prefixed with dotnetfx35_x86.  This is usually much smaller, about 53 MB.

Comment: What is the MBSA? Sorry for being so dense

Comment: Ok, I ran the MBSA and 3.5 SP1 was NOT recommended